# Prestashop 1.7 Update Error

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

When I try to install or update modules in Prestashop 1.7 I get the following error appear in the top right of the screen.

[image]

I have tried to login but it won't let me because of a server setting which is there for security reasons. Is there anyway around this?

> If you want to be able to fully use the AdminModules panel and have free modules available, you should enable the following configuration on your server:
>
> - Enable PHP's `allow_url_fopen` setting.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to login here https://addons.prestashop.com/
then install the app again.
install the whole app again not restarting the same app installation.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from "Addons store" server which host the modules, not with your PrestaShop installation. Wait for PrestaShop to fix it.

Comment: Is there any comment from Prestashop on this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my market logging problem yesterday with the following procedure. You'll need an access to the WHM panel to fix it (or alternatively use SSH, but you'll need a good knowledge of Linux command line).

Once you're logged in WHM:

1. Type "*apache*" in the search box.
2. Click on the "*MultiPHP in Editor*" menu.
3. By default, you should be in "*basic mode*".
4. Select your current version of PHP (by example: 7.0.X.)
5. Enable the "*allow_url_fopen*"

[image: Steps 1-5 to setup allow_url_fopen via the WHM panel]

6. Scroll down and click on the "*apply*" button.
7. I'm always restarting the Apache service to be sure that the new configuration applies.

[image: Steps 6 and 7 to setup allow_url_fopen via the WHM panel]

Alternatively, if you don't have access to WHM:

1. Download the module directly from the marketplace: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/
2. Login in the back-office.
3. Click on the "*modules*" tab in the vertical menu.
4. Click on the "*upload a module*" button (sorry this setup is in French).
   [image: Upload a module in Prestashop]
5. Drag and drop the module archive in the white box.
   [image: Drag and drop module archive]